# DIscrete Math C++

Tags: c++, discrete-mathematics

x^2 + y^2 = Z^2. How to test the truth of Pythagoras Theorem in code? My assignment says to read in 10 integers and test if the statement is true or false with each of the ten integers. This is what I have but I'm not sure if its right because I'm not sure if I'm solving for z.

Any help appreciated

```
void ESearch(int array[], int size)
{
int trueCount = 0;
//int falseCount = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
    {

        int x = array[i];
        int y = array[j];

        int z = sqrt(pow(x, 2)+ pow(y, 2));

        if(z == x || y)
        {
            ++trueCount;
        }

    }


}
if(trueCount > 0) cout << "\nE is TRUE"; else cout << "\nE is FALSE";

 }
```

Comment: if you're going to down-vote at least tell me why.

Comment: The chance of your `trueCount` being incremented is pretty low. Also, *I'm not sure if I'm solving for z* - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element or http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max

Comment: You are looking for [pythagorean triples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) , but you have 10 integers as input. How are going to pair them in order for this to make sense?

Comment: Maybe pic any two of the 10 integers as x and y. and do sqrt(x*x+y*y) and see if the value is any one of the other 8 integers. or vice versa.

Comment: The square root of z^2 does not have to equal x or y. Take for example the triplet (3,4,5).

Comment: `if(z == x || y)` probably doesn't do what you might think it does.

Comment: To test the Pythagoras Theorem you need to have three integers z > y >= x and check `if (z*z == y*y + x*x)`. Not sure how you pick three from the ten. Maybe try all the combinations?

Comment: @RetiredNinja thanks. your coy response really helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code won't work the way you want. Try this. You have very small data size, so most probably you don't care much about efficiency, but I wrote some simple (not yet the most efficient) solution using STL. You define a vector and sort it once in order then to use binary search when you want to check whether the pair `(x,y)` satisfies Pyth. theorem for some other integer from your input data. It takes `log(size)`, so it should be reasonably fast even for large data inputs.
Also you don't need to run second loop from the beginning of the data, since you'll be already checking the same pair but in different order before. 
The code should fairly simple, but if you have any questions, please ask. Good luck.

```
void ESearch(int array[], int size)
{

int trueCount = 0;
std::vector<int> z(array, array + size);
std::sort(z.begin(), z.end());

int x, y;
double z_check;

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    x = array[i];

    for(int j = i+1; j < size; j++)
    {
        y = array[j];

        z_check = sqrt(x*x + y*y);

        if(std::binary_search(z.begin(), z.end(), z_check))
        {
            trueCount++;
        }

    }
}
z.clear();
if(trueCount > 0) cout << trueCount; else cout << "\nE is FALSE";
}
```

EDIT:
You can even speed up things a bit more since you know that you are looking for the number greater than `sqrt(x*x+y*y)` in sorted vector:

```
if(std::binary_search(z.begin() + ceil(z_check), z.end(), z_check))
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up trying all the combinations looking for triples because I felt the ten numbers entered were not substantial enough for a test on pytho. But this is really cool